# Reading text file in blocks MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, text-files

for my assignment reading the text file for further calculation work using MATLAB. So, here my question is how I can read the text data and save the values to Variables as example:

```
A= [vertical angles]; B= [Horizontal angles]; C= [vertical data];
```

I tried the function **`dlmwrite`** as

```
M = dlmread(filename,'/t ',2,0)

a=M(2:3);     ver=M([5:a(1)+4]); 

hor = M([a(1)+4:a(2)+a(1)]);...
```

but the `dlmread()` was successful in reading only half the file size.

I also tried to read the file using **`textscan()`** function with a `while` loop. As the result is in Cell array, which leave me no clue how to separate as per my requirement

```
file =fopen(filename);
line = fgets(file);
data={};
a=1;
while ischar(line)
    ar=textscan(line,'%f');
for i = 1:length(n)
    data{i,a}=ar{i};
end
line=fgets(file);
a=a+1;
end
```

Here is the example of text file order and the file used in my assignment is in order of array sizes data = (1500x1800) ...

```
NAME
PRODUCT
0 24 30 2    % Here 24,30 denotes the vertical and horizontal data which can be considered as Matrix size %
20 21 22 44 25 56 78 79 89 29 59 14   %% vertical angles length(vector)=25
20.5 20.6 20.7 20.9 30 30.9 81 91
15 19 16 18 5     
10 12 13 16 17 18 19 18 20 16 18 15   %% Horizontal angles length(vector)=29
20.6 20.7 20.8 15 14 16 18 19 20 30.5
19 20 16 15.6 18 19 20                
80 51 22 34 25 56 78 29 59 29 59 14   %% here starts the vertical data i.e length of vector 25
20.3 20.6 20.8 20.9 36 30.9 81 91
15 15 18 16 5                        
.
.
.
No. of horizontal i.e 29
```

Comment: Do you have both string and numerical format in your text ?

Comment: @P.Bn yes. Only in the top two rows and those are considered as headings.

Comment: Well your lenths are mismatching... I see 25 values for vertical angles and 29 for horizontal angles. Also (even if it's a problem that can be easily bypassed) the number of elements for each row seems totally random.

Comment: @TommasoBelluzzo Sorry, I miscalculated the length of vector. So, now I have edited it and yes the row consists random length. I like to somehow read line by line and count the length of vector and push it to vertical angle matrix.. and so on..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not very elegant, this does what has to be done, if I understood your needs correctly:

```
values = [];
vert_len = NaN;
horz_len = NaN;

offset = 1;
values_offset = 1;

fid = fopen('myfile.txt');
line = fgetl(fid);

while (ischar(line))

    line = strtrim(line);

    switch (offset)
        case {1 2}

        case 3
            split = strsplit(line,' ');
            header = sscanf(sprintf('%s*',split{:}),'%f*');
            vert_len = header(2);
            horz_len = header(3);

        otherwise
            split = strsplit(line,' ');
            values_line = sscanf(sprintf('%s*',split{:}),'%f*'); 
            values = [values; values_line];

    end

    line = fgets(fid);  
    offset = offset + 1;

end

A = values(1:vert_len);

B_offset_1 = vert_len + 1;
B_offset_2 = B_offset_1 + horz_len - 1;
B = values(B_offset_1:B_offset_2);

C = values(B_offset_2+1:end);
```

This

```
sscanf(sprintf('%s*',mycell{:}),'%f*')
```

is one of the fastest known methods to convert strings to double.

This is the template I used (your template, althrough fixed, is still wrong):

```
NAME
PRODUCT
0 25 29 2
20 21 22 44 25 56 78 79 89 29 59 14
20.5 20.6 20.7 20.9 30 30.9 81 91
15 19 16 18 5     
10 12 13 16 17 18 19 18 20 16 18 15
20.6 20.7 20.8 15 14 16 18 19 20 30.5
19 20 16 15.6 18 19 20                
80 51 22 34 25 56 78 29 59 29 59 14
20.3 20.6 20.8 20.9 36 30.9 81 91
15 15 18 16 5
```

Comment: Thank you. This works, but is would be possible to preallocate array in-order to make this execution a bit faster?

Comment: Yes sure, but things will get trickier because you will have to fill it keeping track of what's going on, and using another offset variable.

Comment: I have done appending to Zeros vector like  declaring ` values=zeros(1,1) ` and in the loop `values=[values(1:end,1);values_line]`. This make the warning sign disappears but, is there any better way to do this?

Comment: Nah that's not good... your values rows should be ((vert_len * 2) + horz_len) and then you insert values keeping track with another offset variable.